# How can I initialize a vector of objects in C++?

Tags: c++

Given the following code:

```
vector<Worker> allWorkers;
allWorkers.resize(10);
for(int i=0; i<allWorkers.size(); i++){
   allWorkers.push_back(Worker());
}
```

The code above doesn't work. All I want is to fill the vector with objects of the type Worker. How can I do this?

Comment: After your edit adding the `resize`, why are you calling `push_back` at all? You already have your workers.

Comment: After your edit: `allWorkers.resize(10);` already fills your vector with 10 default constructed `Worker` instances.

Comment: The code I posted was a simplified version of what I actually wrote.

Comment: @Mahalanobis _"The code I posted was a simplified version ..."_ Don't post arbitrary bogus code, but a [MCVE] showing your exact problem please.

Comment: When you say default constructed Worker instances you mean the no paramteter constructor that I created?

Comment: Yes, that is what default constructed means - they were constructed using the default (no parameter) constructor. If you really did use `.resize(10)` you should have 10 elements in your vector. I agree that you really need a minimal example that demonstrates the problem you are having. In writing the example, you may even find the issue yourself.

Comment: The code you actually posted has an infinite loop, `push_back` increases the size by one and then you recheck the size in the loop condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either one of these would work:

```
vector<Worker> allWorkers;
int numberOfWorkersToAdd = 100; // put whatever number you want here
for(int i=0; i<numberOfWorkersToAdd; i++){
   allWorkers.push_back(Worker());
}
```

Alternatively:

```
vector<Worker> allWorkers;
int numberOfWorkersToAdd = 100; // put whatever number you want here
allWorkers.resize(numberOfWorkersToAdd);
```

Depending on your use case there might be other options too.

Comment: And of course, my favorite: `vector<Worker> allWorkers(100);`

Answer (score 0):

Your program does add any objects to `allWorkers` since `allWorkers` is an empty vector after:

```
vector<Worker> allWorkers;
```

Using

```
size_t size = <some size>;
vector<Worker> allWorkers(size);
```

should do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty vector in the first line.

In your for() loop, you are iterating until you have reached the size of the vector list. In this case, the size is 0, which means that an iteration never happens.

I would first find a way to calculate how many Worker objects you have and use that size as the loop constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just write 
`auto allWorkers = vector<Worker>(100,Worker());`
where 100 is the amount of Workers.

Comment: The second argument is a pessimization ; if it is omitted then the vectors members will be default-constructed in place.